# Error Duplicate class org.simpleframework.xml

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, dependency-management

I am working with a library I created myself that uses simplexml, In my main project where I am using the library I created, I need to use simplexml again. But I am getting an error. I am pasting the stack trace here...

```
Duplicate class org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute found in modules jetified-poslib-host-debug-runtime (poslib-host-debug.aar) and simple-xml-2.7.1 (org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1)
Duplicate class org.simpleframework.xml.Default found in modules jetified-poslib-host-debug-runtime (poslib-host-debug.aar) and simple-xml-2.7.1 (org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1)
Duplicate class org.simpleframework.xml.DefaultType found in modules jetified-poslib-host-debug-runtime (poslib-host-debug.aar) and simple-xml-2.7.1 (org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1)
```

This is just 3 of the error, the list is long. I am sure I can get help by posting only the first 3.

Here is my gradle file,

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.7.1'
```

What I have tried:
I removed the implementation from the library and implemented it in the main project and deleted the simplexml dependency from the library gradle, I invalidate cache and rebuilt my aar file. That did not work

How do I solve this? I saw others use exclude in the gradle file.

Comment: If you have already included `simplexml` dependency in your library than you don't need to add it in your app dependency.

Comment: @DB377,  when I don't add, it complains that it is missing.